# Function with 3 parameters(int,bool,dict) and test to see if int is in dictionary

Tags: python

So I have to make a function called "test" with 3 parameters(int, bool, dict) and the bool is set to True and the dict is {2:3, 4:5, 6:8}. So if bool is True then test to see if int is in dict. If it is then return the value, if not return False. Also the boolean and dict are optional parameters, I don't know if that changes anything. This is my question: Write a function, test, that takes in three parameters: a required integer, an optional boolean whose default value is True, and an optional dictionary, called dict1, whose default value is {2:3, 4:5, 6:8}. If the boolean parameter is True, the function should test to see if the integer is a key in the dictionary. The value of that key should then be returned. If the boolean parameter is False, return the boolean value “False”

```
def test(x, abool = True, dict1 = {2:3, 4:5, 6:8}):
    if abool == True:
        if x in dict1:
            return x
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Can you specify what you actually want?

Comment: Please update your question with example calls to `test()` with sample parameters and expected returns.

Comment: @theodand - This comment should be part of the question.

Comment: instead of returning x, return dict1[x]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if x in dict1:
    return X
```

This will check whether the key is in the dictionary and then return the key, not the value like you want.

It could look like this:

```
if x in dict1:
    return dict1[X]
```

If the key is in the dictionary, return the corresponding value.

Alternatively, you can use the `dict.get(key[, default])` method.

```
return abool and dict1.get(x, False)
```

This will check if x is in the dictionary. If not, it'll return default (`False` in this case). If it is, it returns the corresponding value.

Comment: I just did the second recommendation, thank you

Comment: Your last one isn't quite right; it will return the value of `dict1[x]` even if `abool` is False. Try `return abool and dict.get(x, False)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's not 100% clear what you want or what is wrong. I suggest you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That being said, it seems you want to return the value of the dict instead of the key. To do this you need to call:

```
return dict1[x]
```

instead of

```
return x
```